# How to sort list of objects with field containing both words and numbers?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, object

Currently I have the following list of objects. All the fields are of type string .

```
new PurchaseInvoice{ AccountCode="SUPPLIER1",BookingNo="BKG001",AccountingPeriod="2020002",}
new PurchaseInvoice{ AccountCode="3460",BookingNo="BKG001",AccountingPeriod="2020002",}
new PurchaseInvoice{ AccountCode="5120",BookingNo="BKG001",AccountingPeriod="2020002",}
new PurchaseInvoice{ AccountCode="5120",BookingNo="BKG001",AccountingPeriod="2020002",}
new PurchaseInvoice{ AccountCode=""    ,BookingNo="BKG221",AccountingPeriod="2020002",}
new PurchaseInvoice{ AccountCode="1500",BookingNo="BKG221",AccountingPeriod="2020002",}
new PurchaseInvoice{ AccountCode="3460",BookingNo="BKG221",AccountingPeriod="2020002",}
new PurchaseInvoice{ AccountCode="1500",BookingNo="BKG221",AccountingPeriod="2020005",}
new PurchaseInvoice{ AccountCode="3460",BookingNo="BKG221",AccountingPeriod="2020005",}
new PurchaseInvoice{ AccountCode="5120",BookingNo="BKG221",AccountingPeriod="2020005",}
```

This needs to be sorted first by **Accounting period** and then by **AccountCode** but at the same time they **should be grouped together by BookingNo** .

The **first line of each group should have the Supplier** or empty string if its present.

An empty string " " can also be a **AccountCode**

> Expected output

```
SUPPLIER1  BKG001  2020002
3460       BKG001  2020002
5120       BKG001  2020002
5120       BKG001  2020002
           BKG221  2020002
1500       BKG221  2020002
3460       BKG221  2020002
1500       BKG221  2020005
3460       BKG221  2020005
5120       BKG221  2020005
```

Here is what I tried

```
   //Sort 
            purchaseInvoiceList = purchaseInvoiceList.OrderBy(x => x.AccountingPeriod)
                                            .ThenBy(x => x.AccountCode, new MixedComparer())
                                            .ThenBy(x => x.BookingNo)
                                            .ToList();



 class MixedComparer : IComparer<string>
        {
            public int Compare(string x, string y)
            {
                int xVal, yVal;
                var xIsVal = int.TryParse(x, out xVal);
                var yIsVal = int.TryParse(y, out yVal);

                if (xIsVal && yIsVal)   // both are numbers...
                    return xVal.CompareTo(yVal);
                if (!xIsVal && !yIsVal) // both are strings...
                    return x.CompareTo(y);
                if (xIsVal)             // x is a number, sort first
                    return -1;
                return 1;               // x is a string, sort last
            }
        }
```

> And the result which I got

```
3460       BKG001  2020002
5120       BKG001  2020002
5120       BKG001  2020002
SUPPLIER1  BKG001  2020002
1500       BKG221  2020002
3460       BKG221  2020002
           BKG221  2020002
1500       BKG221  2020005
3460       BKG221  2020005
5120       BKG221  2020005
```

How can this be sorted as per the expected output? Please can someone assist here?

Comment: I beleive you are just missing a `GroupBy(x => x.BookingNo)`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: The difference I see with the expected output is that you place numbers before strings. And that's what your Comparer does anyway. Look at the comments of your code.

Comment: What does this _The first line of each group should have the Supplier or empty string if its present._ mean? you have only one _SUPPLIER1_ and one empty string. Actually `var result = purchaseInvoiceList.OrderBy(x => x.BookingNo).ThenBy(x => x.AccountingPeriod).ToList();` gives you an expected order and leave the first column as is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence of your `OrderBy` were slightly off according to your desired output.

```
var sortedList = purchaseInvoiceList.
    OrderBy(x => x.BookingNo).
    ThenBy(x => x.AccountingPeriod).
    ThenBy(x => x.AccountCode, new MixedComparer());
```

Also, the last two case of your `MixedComparer` were inverted, again according to your desired output:

```
public class MixedComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        int xVal, yVal, result;
        var xIsVal = int.TryParse(x, out xVal);
        var yIsVal = int.TryParse(y, out yVal);

        if (xIsVal && yIsVal)           // both are numbers...
        { result = xVal.CompareTo(yVal); }
        else if (!xIsVal && !yIsVal)    // both are strings...
        { result = x.CompareTo(y); }
        else if (xIsVal)                // x is a number, sort first
        { result = 1; }
        else result = -1;               // x is a string, sort last
        return result;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
SUPPLIER1 : BKG001 : 2020002
3460      : BKG001 : 2020002
5120      : BKG001 : 2020002
5120      : BKG001 : 2020002
          : BKG221 : 2020002
1500      : BKG221 : 2020002
3460      : BKG221 : 2020002
1500      : BKG221 : 2020005
3460      : BKG221 : 2020005
5120      : BKG221 : 2020005
```

Answer (score 2):

your comparer sorts the numbers first and then the strings. it needs to be the other way around

```
public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            int xVal, yVal;
            var xIsVal = int.TryParse(x, out xVal);
            var yIsVal = int.TryParse(y, out yVal);

            if (xIsVal && yIsVal)   // both are numbers...
                return xVal.CompareTo(yVal);
            if (!xIsVal && !yIsVal) // both are strings...
                return x.CompareTo(y);
            if (xIsVal)             // x is a number, sort last<---
                return 1;
            return -1;               // x is a string, sort first<---
        }
```

also, you should sort first by `BookingNo` and the by `AccountCode` and then `AccountingPeriod`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the results grouped by BookingNo first then effectively you need to order by those first, (unless I've misunderstood and you want two record with the same BookingNo to be separated if the have wildly different AccountingPeriod).

As others noted your comparer sorts numbers first, so if you switch the order there it should work, if you want you could also do without a comparer: (might not be as efficent, i honestly don't know)

```
purchaseInvoiceList = purchaseInvoiceList
            .Select(Invoice => (Invoice, !int.TryParse(Invoice.AccountCode, out _) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Invoice.AccountCode) ? 0 : string.IsNullOrEmpty(Invoice.AccountCode) ? 2 : 1))
            .OrderBy(x => x.Invoice.BookingNo)
            .ThenBy(x => x.Invoice.AccountingPeriod)
            .ThenBy(x => x.Item2)
            .ThenBy(x => x.Invoice.AccountCode)
            .Select(x=>x.Invoice)
            .ToList();
```